# getting error IMP-00010: not a valid export file while importing DMP sent by email

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a job assignment to import a DMP oracle db and analyze it .
the problem when i try to analyze it i get the error :

```
Export: Release 11.2.0.1.0
IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

the file was sent by email in compressed .RAR file 
with the following log :

```
Export: Release **11.2.0.3.0** - Production on Tue Jan 10 15:15:08 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

how to fix that ? and if i tried oracle server 12c will i get the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Corruption from compression or FTP - If the export file was
>   manipulated it may have become corrupted.  The most common cause with
>   FTP is using an ASCII transfer and failing to use the binary flag:

check this [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_imp_00010_not_a_valid_export_file.htm) for more infos